# What's the best database if i want save data temporally?

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation, relational-theory, nosql, timestamp

I want to create a datalog system so I need to store some int data temporally. What would be the best database (Relational, NO-SQL or some specific) for that purpose? And what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: How temporary, and do you need to access this data from other systems? My first thought is to tell you to save this as a text file somewhere and not bother with a database, but I don't have enough details on what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: And how *much* data?

Comment: @JohnM not much data maybe record data for a day every 10 min or so. It would be: 144 entries

Comment: @SQLRockstar Well I would have a raspberry that will send to a server the read data and stores in the db so it  have to save something like {'data': 434, 'time': 'Mon Jan 12 2015 21:28:08 GMT+0100 (CET)'}.Thank you for all!

Comment: Temporally? Or temporarily? (@SQLRockstar)

Comment: Ah, yes, I can't read (temporary vs. temporally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at SQLite if I were you but if you are you going to perform many analyses on this data - i.e. windowing functions -or CTEs (common table expressions), in that case, I'd go with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ok, i will try with SQLite because i only want to get the data and display it in a graph. Thank you!